# Data Mining Resources for C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-mining

I wonder if we could compile a list of resources for Data Mining in C#?

Specifically I am looking for

- Implementations of Data Mining Algorithms
- Open Source Data mining libraries
- Tutorials on Data Mining using C#/.net code

& if anyone knows of a C# implementation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm I'd be very interested.

I'll try and summarise the posted results for re-usability

Comment: Why specifically C4.5? Many new classification algorithms have been developed/improved since 1993, including SVMs, voted/averaged perceptrons, SGD...

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for StackOverflow - it's just another poll.

Comment: I gave C4.5 as a well known example of a datamining algorithm.

Comment: There are many questions on SO which ask for advice on which open source libraries to use, can this not be seen in the same ilk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are like me, you can have a look at Weka's Souce Code (its in JAVA - I have a dream to port it into C#.Net, if any one has not already started... there is a J# port... http://sourceforge.net/projects/wekadotnet )

Also look at...
http://datamining.codeplex.com/